# My Citroen C3 2010 model has a problem starting all off a sudden

Tags: starting, service, citroen

It was due for service and i did not take it in, so immediately when it reached a 1000 km without service it stopped starting. i need to kick start it for me to start it. I'm not sure if its the battery or the starter because if the diagnosis doesn't show the issue at hand. can this mean if i take it in for service it will start?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

The lack of service and it not starting will most likely have ***absolutely nothing to do with the other***. There are no presets within the vehicle which tells the car to shut down when xxx amount of miles has accumulated. It is not the intent of a car manufacturer to leave you stranded because you didn't do the maintenance. Some people *never do maintenance* and they are still driving around in their vehicles (albeit doing tons of damage to their mechanical parts!).

Your problem lies elsewhere, though if you took it to the shop to get the service(s) done, they'd most likely be able to fix your car for you as well ... *for a price*.